Proof that there does not exist any rational number $x$ for which $x^2 = 2$ by contradiction using the principle of infinite descent.
I do not understand the proof which is given below. Specifically, I do not understand the part which starts with (*), although I was able to work out all the (why?) parts. I want you to help me understand everything that happens after (*). In particular, I do not understand the process of reducing the problem to smaller values (by infinite iteration?); can you give an explicit example of what is going on along with a detained explanation? Solutions to the (why?) parts can be found by following this link.
From Terence Tao's Analysis I book (3rd edition):

Exercise 4.4.3. Fill in the gaps marked (why?) in the proof of Proposition 4.4.4.


Proposition 4.4.4. There does not exist any rational number $x$ for
which $x^2 = 2$.

Then the proof of Proposition 4.4.4 follows:

Proof. We only give a sketch of a proof; the gaps will be filled in Exercise 4.4.3.


Suppose for sake of contradiction that we had a rational number $x$ for which $x^2 = 2$. Clearly $x$ is not zero. We may assume that $x$ is
positive, for if $x$ were negative then we could just replace $x$ by $−x$ (since $x^2 = (−x)^2$). Thus $x = p/q$ for some positive integers $p$, $q$, so $(p/q)^2 = 2$, which we can rearrange as $p^2 = 2q^2$.


Define a natural number $p$ to be even if $p = 2k$ for some natural number $k$, and odd if $p = 2k + 1$ for some
natural number $k$. Every natural number is either even or odd, but not
both (why?). If $p$ is odd, then $p^2$ is also odd (why?), which contradicts $p^2 = 2q^2$. Thus $p$ is even, i.e., $p = 2k$ for some natural number $k$. Since $p$ is positive, $k$ must also be positive. Inserting $p = 2k$ into $p^2 = 2q^2$ we obtain $4k^2 = 2q^2$, so that $q^2 = 2k^2$.


To summarize, we started with a pair $(p, q)$ of positive integers such
that $p^2 = 2q^2$, and ended up with a pair $(q, k)$ of positive integers such
that $q^2 = 2k^2$. Since $p^2 = 2q^2$, we have $q < p$ (why?).


(*) If we rewrite $p′ := q$ and $q′ := k$, we thus can pass from one solution $(p, q)$ to the equation $p^2 = 2q^2$ to a new solution $(p′, q′)$ to the same equation which has a smaller value of $p$. But then we can repeat this procedure again and again, obtaining a sequence $(p′′, q′′)$, $(p′′′, q′′′)$, etc. of solutions to $p^2 = 2q^2$, each one with a smaller value of $p$ than the previous, and each one consisting of positive integers. But this contradicts the principle of infinite descent. This contradiction shows that we could not have had a rational $x$ for which $x^2 = 2$.

The principle of infinite descent for natural numbers states that it is not possible to have a sequence of natural numbers which is in infinite descent. That is, it is not possible to construct an infinite sequence of natural numbers such that $a_n > a_{n+1} > a_{n+2} > ...$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. More information about this principle can be found by following this link.

Note that the usual proof involving Euclid's lemma (if $p$ is prime and $p=ab$ then $p$ either divide $a$ or divide $b$), is simpler but requires the knowledge of this particular lemma and gcd stuff.
Indeed it goes like :
let $x=\frac pq$ be an irreductible fraction, i.e. $\gcd(p,q)=1$
Then assuming $x^2=2\iff p^2=2q^2$ then since $2$ is prime it divides $p$ (this is also shown in the book's proof differently).
So $p=2k$ and $4k^2=2q^2\iff q^2=2k^2$ and similarly $2$ divides $q$
Therefore $2$ divides $p$ and $q$ contradicting $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Instead of using this final argument (with gcd), the books goes specifically for an infinite descent instead.
The argument is that if you start with a couple some numbers $p,q$ that verify $p^2=2q^2$ you end up with two other numbers $q,k$ that should also verify the same equation $q^2=2k^2$.
If you continue you would get $q=2m$ and it would result in $k^2=2m^2$ and so on.
So the initial problem seems to never solve because it went from proving something on $(p,q)$ to proving the same on $(q,k)$ to proving the same on $(k,m)$, and so on $\cdots$
Fortunately these numbers are strictly smaller and smaller, and since they are positive integers this cannot go forever.
So the core of the proof relies on these numbers being smaller and smaller.
$q\ge p\implies q^2\ge p^2\implies 2q^2\ge q^2+p^2>p^2$ (since $q>0$) which is not possible so $q<p$
$k\ge q\implies k^2\ge q^2\implies p^2\ge 4q^2>2q^2$ (since $q>0$) which is not possible so $k<q$
So you go from $(p,q)$ to $(q,k)$ with $q<p$ and $k<q$ and similarly you would go to a strictly smaller $(k,m)$ and so on.

I really appreciate your detailed explanation; can you explain to me the last two implications that you wrote? Specifically, I do not understand how you conclude that $q < p$ and $k < q$.

I do it by absurd proof. I suppose $q\ge p$ and end up with $p^2<2q^2$ which is a contradiction since they verify the equation $p^2=2q^2$. So the opposite should be true, i.e. $q<p$
